# How can I add PHP executable to VSCODE?

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-extensions, vscode-debugger

I have been searching web for a long for a correct way to use vscode editor for PHP debug and get confused with lot of result. When I run > start debug F5 from menu on vscode within a php page I am getting this prompt

[image]

when I click the edit in settings.json, I am getting this

```
{
    "workbench.colorTheme": "Solarized Dark",
    "workbench.editorAssociations": {
        "*.ipynb": "jupyter-notebook"
    },
    "editor.suggestSelection": "first",
    "vsintellicode.modify.editor.suggestSelection": "automaticallyOverrodeDefaultValue",
    "workbench.startupEditor": "none",
    "[php]": {
        "editor.defaultFormatter": "kokororin.vscode-phpfmt"
    },
    "notebook.cellToolbarLocation": {
        "default": "right",
        "jupyter-notebook": "left"
    },
    "editor.fontSize": 15,
    "editor.cursorBlinking": "smooth",
    "editor.cursorSmoothCaretAnimation": true,
    "editor.formatOnType": true,
    "auto-close-tag.fullMode": true,
    "auto-close-tag.insertSpaceBeforeSelfClosingTag": true,
    "auto-close-tag.SublimeText3Mode": true,
    "python.languageServer": "None",
    "html.format.templating": true
}
```

Now from web search I found I must add this line to the above json script

```
"php.validate.executablePath": "C:xampp/php/php.exe"
```

My php has also successfully running xdebug which I manage to start with help of web search. Now only thing which I miss (hope so) is to add the above path to vscode setting which I don't know where to add. Please help me to get this to get done. Thanks in advance.

Comment: You should have a launch.json file in your directory, that's where the php path is defined, at least that's how I do it.

Comment: Hi @crimson589 can you give any tutorials or something else which show those json code script ? thank you for the response

Comment: Try this https://www.codewall.co.uk/debug-php-in-vscode-with-xdebug/